# Send email with image - sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I have a workflow and in the middle of the process it sends email with some data and among them need to put the company logo.
However, when I receive the e-mail is requested login and password to access the image.

The parent site is not allowed to access anonymous and the subsites have the same permissions as parent site.

I tried to put the image inside a physical folder on the server and when i receive the email the image is not loaded / found.

Comment: You get credential request when you open your email in Outlook? If yes then does account which you use for Outlook has permissions on SharePoint?

Comment: When I get the email (Outlook, Gmail, Live Mail) it asks for the credentials to access the Sharepoint. Can not set Outlook, the email will be to sent lay clients. The great problem is that the "parent site" of my application does not have permission to access anonymous

Answer (score 0):

You can place company logo to the separete IIS site or ftp source with anonymous access then use this link in emails and as logo file for "parent site"